# Why does JWPlayer show black bars above and below videos?

Tags: jwplayer

JWPlayer 6 shows black bars above and below video when video is played on iPhone or android smart phones in portrait mode, but not in landscape mode! Same thing happens on iPad when video player width is reduced to 320px or less. The video I used for testing has an aspect ratio of 16:9 and meta data width and height of 640, 360.

Why is this happening and more importantly how can the bars be removed without stretching/cropping the video that using different "streching" values ("fill", "exactfit", "none") cause?

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/hRAKQ/17/

JS code:

```
var jw = jwplayer("test").setup({
    file: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4",
    image: "http://lorempixel.com/320/180/sports/7/",
    width: 320,
    height: 180,
    autoplay: false
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will work:

```
var jw = jwplayer("test").setup({
    file: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4",
    image: "http://lorempixel.com/320/180/sports/7/",
    width: 320,
    height: 180,
    autoplay: false,
    stretching: 'exactfit'
});
```

Comment: As I said in my post above this is not a good solution as it not only distorts poster/video by stretching them vertically, but also distorts player bar on iPad iOS5.1 (for example the progress bar disappears).

Comment: Another thing you can try is fill.

Comment: Also I would advise updating from 6.1 to 6.5.

Comment: I have tried all various stretching options, fill comes closet but even that increases the video height. Why do the black bars appear at all when all dimensions are correct?

Comment: Upgrading to jwplayer 6.5 didn't resolve the problem either! :(

Comment: I think it actually has something to do with your site's CSS and our HTML5 player. Try to set the primary variable to flash, as well.

Comment: Why should setting primary variable to Flash make any difference? After all the problem appears on iPhone and android devices which by default don't support Flash. I don't think the problem has to do with CSS since it appears on jsfiddle too.

Comment: I think it might. Do you see the same issues on - http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. Though the black bar only appears at the bottom and only when the play button is clicked. I got mine to work with the css hack of setting the font-size to zero on the video div element. So in your fiddle example it would be like this

```
<div id="test" style="font-size: 0"></div>
```